# Responsive list items

Tags: responsive-design, html-lists

I have a list items and I would like them auto expand to parent width. My html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="playlistHolder">
    <div class="playlist_inner">
        <ul>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
          <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

wrapper needs to be 100% browser width.

playlistHolder and list items inside need to be 100% width and responsive so they follow the width of the wrapper.

How can I achieve that with css?

Comment: If your wrapper needs to be 100% browser width, why don't you use your <body> instead of this <div class="wrapper"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umZb8/1/

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.playlistHolder {
  width: 100%; 
}

.playlist_inner ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;    
}

.playlist_inner ul > li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make this list have certain height with a vertical scrollbar appear?

Comment: You have to define the height (`height: 50px;`) and add the overflow property (`overflow-y: scroll;`) of your **playlistHolder**. Additionally you can use the resize property (`resize: vertical;`) with you want to the user resize the box. Take a look at the updated fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/umZb8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to build a [Responsive Layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) you have to use [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). In your case (if I understand correctly the question), it's enough to set wrapper's width as `auto`. All child items will inherit width value of their parent.

```
div.wrapper {
    width: auto;
    background: #abcdef;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

div.playlistHolder {
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.playlist_inner
{
    width: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #000cee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.playlist_inner > ul {
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
}

div.playlist_inner > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

This is the output:

[image: html+css output]